# Setting workspace environment for hosted feature layers

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-000732, workspace, hosted-feature-layer

I have a simple script that I want to use to export multiple hosted feature layers at once. This is my code:

```
import arcpy

fcList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  #input hosted feature layers 
out_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  #output geodatabase
p_info = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  #project name text to append onto input layer name
arcpy.overwriteOutput = True

proj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT') #set project

#export all the feature services to a geodatabase

for fc in fcList:
    outputFeatures = fc + '_' + p_info
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fcList, out_workspace, outputFeatures)
```

I am getting these errors:

ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset 'Data Point';'Ground Control Point layer' does not exist or is not supported
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

I know that feature layers are supported in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 since I can use them as inputs for the Feature Class to Feature Class tool. I have a Basic License, when I export feature layers to gdb using the regular tool, I get the Message Warning #001102, You must have at least the Standard License to run this tool with the specified data. The data exports fine though, so I tend to ignore this message. None of the feature layers have attachments.

To fix this script, do I need to specify the workspace?

[image]

I have a parameter for the input features (fcList), which is a multivalue. I do not have an "in" workspace parameter. I only have the output gdb as a workspace parameter.

Is my issue related to the fact that I am working with feature layers, or I have not set the workspace?

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved similar in the past with the below code. I have commented but let me know if anything needs clarification. Basically it uses a combination of the ArcGIS Python API and ArcPy to access the feature services and export layers to feature classes in a gdb.

```
from arcgis import GIS
import arcpy

## set to True if you want any attachments to also be exported
## a lot faster to ignore any attachments if they are not needed as output
arcpy.env.maintainAttachments = False

## access AGOL
conn = GIS("home")

## you could change this to a list of feature service ids and iterate to
## export them to gdb
## get the item ID from the Feature Service page on AGOL, it is in the URL
## bar at the top of the browser 
fs_id = "INSERT ITEM ID"

## gdb path to export to
out_gdb = r"INSERT GDB PATH"

## get the fs content, here is where you could loop through multiple feature
## service ids and export
item = conn.content.get(fs_id)

## use item.tables if interested in non-spatial tables
for lyr in item.layers:
    ## you might need to use the string replace function and replace any
    ## spaces with underscores as fc naming wont allow spaces and the
    ## feature class to feature class tool will fail.
    fc_name = lyr.properties.name
    ## at this point you could use an if statement if you are only interested 
    ## in layers with a certain name
    print(fc_name)
    ## get direct url to the layer within the feature service
    fc = lyr.url
    ## export to gdb
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, out_gdb, fc_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is it possible to use the GetParameterAtText for the fs_id? Example: fs_id = GetParameterAsText(). I cannot hard code the input. I want the tool user to be able to choose the feature services to pass to Feature Class to Feature Class. That is the crux for me.

Comment: Yes, you can have it as a single input for one feature service or as multiple input, you will just need to add in code to handle the loop/iteration of the multiple id entries.